# Assemble daily activity histogram data from job start and end times

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find a pure SQL (Oracle) way to reveal how many jobs are running at various times of day in a batch scheduling system. The [database table](https://docs.automic.com/documentation/webhelp/english/AA/21.0/AE/12.3/DB%20Schema/db/_structure/HTML/AH.html) contains historical data about past runs of jobs, including the start time (`AH_TimeStamp1`) and the end time (`AH_TimeStamp4`).

My aim is to assemble data for plotting a histogram with the time of day on the X-axis and the number of jobs per time subdivision on the Y-axis. The time subdivisions could be hours (24 divisions per day) or finer-grained such as 10-minute intervals. Ideally the query should be constructed so that both the number of subdivisions per day and the offset from midnight are easily adjustable.

I could perform lots of UNIONs — one per time subdivision — but this seems inelegant and tedious, particularly for smaller time subdivisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first answer above works fine for small datasets. But if you have a massive data set, and particularly if you want fine-grained time slots, you will need a divide and conquer strategy to make it acceptably performant.  The SQL below is based on the principal that a hash join on an equality is eminently desirable to reduce the size of the temporary Cartesian product join between your date ticks and your time-range data. Some date ranges will have the same hour for start & end. Some will have the same minute. Some will be within 30 mins of each other, etc.. You can take advantage of this by progressively taking these rows from the closest pairings (same minute) progressively up to the more distant pairings (same 12 hour period), using a hash join in each case on the equality of each period bucket. Then pick up any stragglers that defy all your bucketizing at the end without any equality. Hopefully that will be a small set. Here's the SQL:

```
    WITH ahx AS (SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) MATERIALIZE */
                   ah_timestamp1,
                   ah_timestamp3,
                   TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ah.ah_timestamp1) + (FLOOR((ah.ah_timestamp1 - TRUNC(ah.ah_timestamp1))*2)/2),'HH24') ah_start_12hour,
                   TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ah.ah_timestamp3) + (FLOOR((ah.ah_timestamp3 - TRUNC(ah.ah_timestamp3))*2)/2),'HH24') ah_end_12hour,
                   TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ah.ah_timestamp1) + (FLOOR((ah.ah_timestamp1 - TRUNC(ah.ah_timestamp1))*6)/6),'HH24') ah_start_4hour,
                   TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ah.ah_timestamp3) + (FLOOR((ah.ah_timestamp3 - TRUNC(ah.ah_timestamp3))*6)/6),'HH24') ah_end_4hour,
                   TO_CHAR(ah.ah_timestamp1,'HH24') ah_start_hour,
                   TO_CHAR(ah.ah_timestamp3,'HH24') ah_end_hour,
                   TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ah.ah_timestamp1) + (FLOOR((ah.ah_timestamp1 - TRUNC(ah.ah_timestamp1))*48)/48),'HH24:MI') ah_start_30mins,
                   TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ah.ah_timestamp3) + (FLOOR((ah.ah_timestamp3 - TRUNC(ah.ah_timestamp3))*48)/48),'HH24:MI') ah_end_30mins,
                   TO_CHAR(ah.ah_timestamp1,'HH24:MI') ah_start_min,
                   TO_CHAR(ah.ah_timestamp3,'HH24:MI') ah_end_min
              FROM ah),
     ticks AS (SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE */
                      tick,
                      divisor,
                      time_offset,
                      TO_CHAR(TRUNC(tick_date) + (FLOOR((tick_date - TRUNC(tick_date))*2)/2),'HH24') tick_12hour,
                      TO_CHAR(TRUNC(tick_date) + (FLOOR((tick_date - TRUNC(tick_date))*6)/6),'HH24') tick_4hour,
                      TO_CHAR(tick_date,'HH24') tick_hour,
                      TO_CHAR(TRUNC(tick_date) + (FLOOR((tick_date - TRUNC(tick_date))*48)/48),'HH24:MI') tick_30mins,
                      TO_CHAR(tick_date,'HH24:MI') tick_min
                 FROM (SELECT ROWNUM tick, 
                              divisor,
                              ((ROWNUM-1)/divisor) time_offset,
                              TRUNC(SYSDATE)+((ROWNUM-1)/divisor) tick_date
                         FROM (SELECT 144 divisor FROM dual)
                      CONNECT BY level < divisor))
SELECT time_period,
       SUM(cnt) cnt
  FROM (SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) USE_HASH(ahx ticks) */
               TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ahx.ah_timestamp1)+time_offset,'HH24:MI') time_period,
               COUNT(*) cnt,
               'min' bucket
          FROM ticks,
               ahx
         WHERE ahx.ah_start_min = ahx.ah_end_min
           AND ticks.tick_min = ahx.ah_start_min
           AND TRUNC(ahx.ah_timestamp1)+time_offset BETWEEN ahx.ah_timestamp1 AND ahx.ah_timestamp4
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ahx.ah_timestamp1)+time_offset,'HH24:MI')  
        UNION ALL
        SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) USE_HASH(ahx ticks) */
               TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ahx.ah_timestamp1)+time_offset,'HH24:MI') time_period,
               COUNT(*) cnt,
               '30 mins' bucket
          FROM ticks,
               ahx
         WHERE ahx.ah_start_min != ahx.ah_end_min
           AND ahx.ah_start_30mins = ahx.ah_end_30mins
           AND ticks.tick_30mins = ahx.ah_start_30mins
           AND TRUNC(ahx.ah_timestamp1)+time_offset BETWEEN ahx.ah_timestamp1 AND ahx.ah_timestamp4
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ahx.ah_timestamp1)+time_offset,'HH24:MI')   
        UNION ALL
        SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) USE_HASH(ahx ticks) */
               TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ahx.ah_timestamp1)+time_offset,'HH24:MI') time_period,
               COUNT(*) cnt,
               'hour' bucket
          FROM ticks,
               ahx
         WHERE ahx.ah_start_30mins != ahx.ah_end_30mins
           AND ahx.ah_start_hour = ahx.ah_end_hour
           AND ticks.tick_hour = ahx.ah_start_hour
           AND TRUNC(ahx.ah_timestamp1)+time_offset BETWEEN ahx.ah_timestamp1 AND ahx.ah_timestamp4
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ahx.ah_timestamp1)+time_offset,'HH24:MI')   
        UNION ALL
        SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) USE_HASH(ahx ticks) */
               TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ahx.ah_timestamp1)+time_offset,'HH24:MI') time_period,
               COUNT(*) cnt,
               '4 hour' bucket
          FROM ticks,
               ahx
         WHERE ahx.ah_start_hour != ahx.ah_end_hour
           AND ahx.ah_start_4hour = ahx.ah_end_4hour
           AND ticks.tick_4hour = ahx.ah_start_4hour
           AND TRUNC(ahx.ah_timestamp1)+time_offset BETWEEN ahx.ah_timestamp1 AND ahx.ah_timestamp4
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ahx.ah_timestamp1)+time_offset,'HH24:MI')   
        UNION ALL
        SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) USE_HASH(ahx ticks) */
               TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ahx.ah_timestamp1)+time_offset,'HH24:MI') time_period,
               COUNT(*) cnt,
               '12 hour' bucket
          FROM ticks,
               ahx
         WHERE ahx.ah_start_4hour != ahx.ah_end_4hour
           AND ahx.ah_start_12hour = ahx.ah_end_12hour
           AND ticks.tick_12hour = ahx.ah_start_12hour
           AND TRUNC(ahx.ah_timestamp1)+time_offset BETWEEN ahx.ah_timestamp1 AND ahx.ah_timestamp4
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ahx.ah_timestamp1)+time_offset,'HH24:MI')   
        UNION ALL
        SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) USE_HASH(ahx ticks) */
               TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ahx.ah_timestamp1)+time_offset,'HH24:MI') time_period,
               COUNT(*) cnt,
               'other' bucket
          FROM ticks,
               ahx
         WHERE ahx.ah_start_12hour != ahx.ah_end_12hour
           AND ahx.ah_start_4hour != ahx.ah_end_4hour
           AND ahx.ah_start_hour != ahx.ah_end_hour
           AND ahx.ah_start_30mins != ahx.ah_end_30mins
           AND ahx.ah_start_min != ahx.ah_end_min
           AND TRUNC(ahx.ah_timestamp1)+time_offset BETWEEN ahx.ah_timestamp1 AND ahx.ah_timestamp4
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ahx.ah_timestamp1)+time_offset,'HH24:MI')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT tick_min time_period,
               0 cnt,
               'empty' bucket
          FROM ticks)
  GROUP BY time_period        
  ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: That's excellent. I haven't tested it on the full table with 167 million rows, but I tested it on a smaller table with only 200 thousand rows, and it returns results in just a few seconds.

Comment: By the way, I discovered that `AH_TimeStamp3` is almost always null, and `AH_TimeStamp4` is actually the correct field to use for job end time.

Comment: There are some time periods that have no jobs, and because it's for a histogram, I'd like to see a result of 0 for these rather than no result. I guess I need to add one more bucket that contains a count of 0 for each time division. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Just add another UNION ALL piece that queries ticks by itself, and present 0 as its cnt.

Comment: I tried to make two changes to the SQL query in your reply, but I'm not seeing the changes reflected here. The changes: 1. I changed `AH_TimeStamp3` to `AH_TimeStamp4`; and 2. I added the following `SELECT` to the top of the subquery with the various buckets. `SELECT tick_min time_period, 0 cnt, 'empty' bucket FROM ticks UNION ALL`

Comment: No problem, there's no need to edit my response...  you should have what you need to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate a calendar of hours or minutes or whatever and drive your count off each of them. Something like this:

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ah.ah_timestamp1)+((tick-1)/divisor),'HH24:MI') hour_of_day,
       COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT ROWNUM tick,24 divisor
          FROM dual
        CONNECT BY level < 24) x,
       archiver_header ah
 WHERE TRUNC(ah.ah_timestamp1)+((tick-1)/divisor) BETWEEN ah.ah_timestamp1 AND ah.ah_timestamp3
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ah.ah_timestamp1)+((tick-1)/divisor),'HH24:MI')
```

For 10-minute intervals, change the divisor to 144.

Comment: I let this query run for more than an hour before cancelling it. I suspect there's a mistake somewhere. I notice that there's no `START WITH` or `PRIOR` in the statement. Was this intentional?

By the way, I had to remove the misplaced label `archiver_header` to get the query to pass the syntax check.

Comment: There's no mistake in the CONNECT BY block... that's a way of generating dummy rows. The archiver_header I took as the table name from the link you provided in your question. If that's not the table, replace it with whatever the proper table is... it isn't a label, it's a table object. You may also rewrite the join using ANSI syntax if you prefer, it doesn't matter.  If it's taking forever, then you must be working with a very large amount of data, and/or have changed the divisor... 24 will be a lot faster than 144, and many times faster than 1440... the fewer ticks, the faster.

Comment: OK, the fact that the table contains nearly 167 million rows is probably relevant. The table is called `AH`. "Archive header" is the description. I'm going to add a predicate to limit the results to one or two days' worth of data.

Comment: Yep, 167 million rows x 24 = 4 billion intermediate row combinations before the GROUP BY takes effect. For 10-minute intervals, that would be 24 billion intermediate rows.